# Best way to show sum of Datagridview column sum dynamically just below the end row as in Excel?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I know this question is asked many times but i didn't find suitable answer :(

I would like to show sum of e.g.Total Price at the end of price column.

As the values changes dynamically(within program) sum also should be changed dynamically. I cannot add custom extra row as DatagridViews are databound.

As there are dynamic rows and many Datagridviews placed inside Table Layout. (It is not desirable to custom paint event as scroll bar also appears sometimes)

I am totally lost. Could anyone suggest the better approach ?

Comment: put a textbox below the table.

Comment: You should mention what answers you've found and why they aren't suitable for your case, mostly to avoid people answering and you saying "that doesn't work for me". Also, not sure but maybe this question fits better on [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Consider control libraries created by third part "Telerik" or "DevExpress" or some else. I am sure they have DataGridView controls which implement summary row. Or create your own WPF control which can be used in the WInforms through `ElementHost` control. WPF more flexible then Winforms in your case

Answer (score 2):

If you are sourcing your `DataGridView` from a `DataTable`, I've already created the following solution when I once encountered this issue.*

The idea is to indicate which columns require summing, which column and text will indicate the "Total" label, then take the underlying `DataTable` and manually sum the indicated columns. These sums and the label are used to create a new DataRow, which is added to the end of the table. When any changes are made - programmatic adding of a new row, deleting a row, sorting - the old *sum row* is removed and a new one is calculated then added.

**The DataGridView Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestSortWithSum
{
  public class DataTableSumSortableDGV : DataGridView
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Column index for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    private int labelColumnIndex = -1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Text for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    private string labelColumnText = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor. Initialize sort direction and subscribe event.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTableSumSortableDGV()
      : base()
    {
      this.SumColumnIndices = new ObservableCollection<int>();
      this.Direction = string.Empty;
      this.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
      this.AllowUserToAddRowsChanged += DataTableSumSortableDGV_AllowUserToAddRowsChanged;
      this.DataBindingComplete += DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete;
      this.DataSourceChanged += DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataSourceChanged;
      this.SumColumnIndices.CollectionChanged += SumColumnIndices_CollectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    public string LabelColumnText
    {
      get
      {
        return this.labelColumnText;
      }

      set
      {
        Action action = () =>
          {
            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.RemoveSumRow();
            }

            this.labelColumnText = value;

            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.AddSumRow();
            }
          };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Column index for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    public int LabelColumnIndex
    {
      get
      {
        return this.labelColumnIndex;
      }

      set
      {
        Action action = () =>
          {
            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.RemoveSumRow();
            }

            this.labelColumnIndex = value;

            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.AddSumRow();
            }
          };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Column indices for the sum(s).
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<int> SumColumnIndices { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DataTable sort direction.
    /// </summary>
    private string Direction { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DataTable source.
    /// </summary>
    private DataTable DataTable { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DataTable sum row.
    /// </summary>
    private DataRow SumRow { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// DataGridView Sort method.
    /// If DataSource is DataTable, special sort the source.
    /// Else normal sort.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGridViewColumn">The DataGridViewColumn to sort by header click.</param>
    /// <param name="direction">The desired sort direction.</param>
    public override void Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection direction)
    {
      if (this.HasSumColumns())
      {
        Action action = () =>
        {
          this.RemoveSumRow();

          string col = this.DataTable.Columns[dataGridViewColumn.Index].ColumnName;

          if (!this.Direction.Contains(col))
          {
            this.ClearOldSort();
          }

          string sort = this.Direction.Contains("ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
          this.Direction = string.Format("{0} {1}", col, sort);

          this.SortRows(this.Direction);
          this.AddSumRow();
        };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
        dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = this.Direction.Contains("ASC") ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
      }
      else
      {
        this.DataTable.DefaultView.Sort = string.Empty;
        base.Sort(dataGridViewColumn, direction);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DataBindingComplete event handler.
    /// Add the sum row when DataSource = a new DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">This DataGridView object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs.</param>
    private void DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
      this.DataTable = (DataTable)this.DataSource;
      this.AddInitialSumRow();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For a new DataSource, start with a fresh SumRow.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The DataGridView object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The EventArgs.</param>
    void DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.SumRow = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prevent users from adding a row as this is DataSourced and rows should be added to the DataTable instead.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The DataGridView object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The EventArgs.</param>
    private void DataTableSumSortableDGV_AllowUserToAddRowsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.AllowUserToAddRows)
      {
        this.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The sum columns have been altered. Reflect the change immediately.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The SumColumnIndices object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.</param>
    private void SumColumnIndices_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.AddInitialSumRow();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the sum row for the first time: once the DataTable is sourced and
    /// the label column index, label text, and sum column index are set.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddInitialSumRow()
    {
      if (this.HasSumColumns())
      {
        Action action = () =>
        {
          this.RemoveSumRow();
          this.AddSumRow();
        };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the sum row to the DataTable as a ReadOnly row.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddSumRow()
    {
      List<decimal> sum = this.CreateListOfSums();
      List<int> exclude = new List<int>();

      for (int row = 0; row < this.DataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
      {
        for (int index = 0; index < this.SumColumnIndices.Count; index++)
        {
          try
          {
            int col = this.SumColumnIndices[index];
            decimal value = 0;

            if (Decimal.TryParse(this.DataTable.Rows[row].ItemArray[col].ToString(), out value))
            {
              sum[index] += value;
            }
            else if (!exclude.Contains(col))
            {
              exclude.Add(col);
            }
          }
          catch (RowNotInTableException)
          {
            continue;
          }
        }
      }

      object[] items = this.CreateItemsArray(this.DataTable.Columns.Count, sum, exclude);

      if (Array.TrueForAll<object>(items, item => { return item == null; }))
      {
        this.SumRow = null;
      }
      else
      {
        this.SumRow = this.DataTable.NewRow();
        this.SumRow.ItemArray = items;
        this.DataTable.Rows.Add(this.SumRow);

        if (this.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
          this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].ReadOnly = true;
        } 
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear the old sort string and any set glyph directions in header cells.
    /// </summary>
    private void ClearOldSort()
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Direction))
      {
        string[] sortVals = this.Direction.Split(new char[] { ' ' }); // [ "ColName", "ASC/DESC" ]
        this.Columns[sortVals[0]].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
      }

      this.Direction = string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the items array for the new sum row.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="length">The array length for the items.</param>
    /// <param name="sum">The list of sums.</param>
    /// <param name="exclude">The list of sum columns that aren't actually sum columns.</param>
    /// <returns>Object array for the sum row.</returns>
    private object[] CreateItemsArray(int length, List<decimal> sum, List<int> exclude)
    {
      object[] items = new object[length];

      if (this.IsValidIndex())
      {
        items[this.LabelColumnIndex] = this.LabelColumnText;
      }

      for (int index = 0; index < this.SumColumnIndices.Count; index++)
      {
        int col = this.SumColumnIndices[index];

        if (!exclude.Contains(col))
        {
          items[col] = sum[index];
        }
      }
      return items;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a list of sums for each sum column index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A new list of sums.</returns>
    private List<decimal> CreateListOfSums()
    {
      List<decimal> sum = new List<decimal>();

      foreach (int index in this.SumColumnIndices)
      {
        sum.Add(0m);
      }

      return sum;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if the index is a valid column for the label.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the index is valid.</returns>
    private bool IsValidIndex()
    {
      return
        this.LabelColumnIndex >= 0 &&
        this.LabelColumnIndex < this.DataTable.Columns.Count &&
        this.DataTable.Columns[this.LabelColumnIndex].DataType == typeof(string);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribe the DataBindingComplete event handler, call internal sorting changes,
    /// then re-subscribe to the DataBindingComplete event handler. This must be done
    /// with any item removal/addition to the DataSource DataTable to prevent recursion
    /// resulting in a Stack Overflow.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation">The internal changes to be made to the DataSource.</param>
    private void MakeInternalChanges(Action operation)
    {
      this.DataBindingComplete -= DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete;
      operation();
      this.DataBindingComplete += DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove any existing sum row.
    /// </summary>
    private void RemoveSumRow()
    {
      if (this.SumRow != null)
      {
        this.DataTable.Rows.Remove(this.SumRow);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if the grid has sum sortable columns.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// True if the source and sum column(s) exist.
    /// False if any one condition fails = sort as normal DataGridView.
    /// </returns>
    private bool HasSumColumns()
    {
      return this.DataTable != null && this.SumColumnIndices.Count > 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sort the DataTable by re-ordering the actual items.
    /// Get the sorted row order. For each sorted row,
    /// remove it from the original list, then re-add it to the end.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sort">The "ColumnName ASC/DESC" sort string.</param>
    private void SortRows(string sort)
    {
      DataRow[] sortedRows = this.DataTable.Select(string.Empty, sort);

      foreach (DataRow row in sortedRows)
      {
        object[] items = (object[])row.ItemArray.Clone();
        this.DataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
        this.DataTable.Rows.Add(items);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

Simply replace your instance of the `DataGridView` with this class:

```
DataTableSumSortableDGV dataGridView1 = new DataTableSumSortableDGV();
```

Then, indicate your sum columns and label column like so:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = GoGetTheDataTable();
this.dataGridView1.SumColumnIndices.Add(3);
this.dataGridView1.SumColumnIndices.Add(4);
this.dataGridView1.LabelColumnIndex = 2;
this.dataGridView1.LabelColumnText = "Total";
```

Order of the above lines doesn't matter, it should work. Below I captured an example demonstrating the behaviors in action:

[image: Example in action]

<sub>* Or you could of course just add a `TextBox`, but I personally didn't like the look of that approach.</sub>

Comment: If I understand right, this works only if DataTable have Columns of type String or you cannot use labels "Total" ja "Sum"

Comment: @Fabio Fixes implemented to allow sum columns without specifying labels, et al. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I think this will not work if user uses different `DataTable` instances for updating data. For example: `this.DataGridView1.DataSource = GenerateNewDataTableInstance();` - in this case your variable `this.SumRow` have reference to the DataRow of previous DataTable

Comment: I afraid another problem will be in the case where Sum of values will be bigger then Maximum value of the underlying type.

Comment: @Fabio Good catches again. I've addressed the DataSource change, and  handled non-summable columns being indexed as a sum column. I could not think of a good way to handle exceeding the Maximum value for sums - but it is an edge case and should the user be exceeding that, I'm not sure how useful knowing that sum really can be - so I'll let the end user handle that error unless an idea comes to light.