# static row in datagridview using windows application C#.net windows application

Tags: c#, datagridview

Am developing an software using windows application. In that i display the records using datagridview, In that i need the first row as static(i.e, while do ascending and descending the the first will be the same place) and ascending and descending will be done in second row. How can i do that, Can any one help me about this.

Answer (score 0):

This is no small task, but it's certainly doable. Generally speaking, you will need to derive a class from the `DataGridView` class. In this new class, you need to handle numerous events in order to:

- Remove the first data source item.
- Manually trigger a sort on the data.
- Insert the first item back into the source.
- Remember the column and sort direction for next time.

I have an extensive example where similarly, a (static) row has been added to the bottom of a DataGridView as a [sum row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399630/3773066). The same idea can apply here - handle the `Sort` method:

```
public override void Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection direction)
{
    this.RemoveFirstItemFromDataSource();

    string col = dataGridViewColumn.Name;

    if (!this.Direction.Contains(col))
    {
        this.ClearPreviousSort();
    }

    string sort = this.Direction.Contains("ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
    this.Direction = string.Format("{0} {1}", col, sort);

    this.ManuallySortSource(this.Direction);
    this.AddFirstItemToDataSource();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Am try to implement as you said.