# Show Total of column values in dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am a newbie in C# so I don't know if I will address my problem correctly so please bear with me.

I have a dataGridView named dgvShowAllData which has a data source coming from my sqlServer. there are a column named Price.
I want to add a new row at the end of the rows in my dataGridView to show the total of the Price column values.
I've tried multiple solutions and got several errors.
I have found a solution that the sum will execute from the sqlServer.
like below,

```
Select Sum(Price) from tblProduct
```

but I got stuck there too. I don't exactly know how to execute two data source in a dataGridview.
Please show me a better way so than I can get the total at the very end of my dataGridView.

Comment: `Double result = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvShowAllData.Rows)
        {
            result += (Double)row.Cells["Price"].Value;
        }`

Comment: how do I add this row in my dataTable?
I have These on my code,

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

Please Help. And thanks for your response

Comment: `var newRowIndex = dgvShowAllData.Rows.Add()`

Comment: I am getting this error,
Rows cannot be programmatically added to the dataGridView's row collection, when the control is data bound.

Comment: If you have a datasource set in the datagrid, rows cannot be added programmatically. You have to decide what you want to do. you can add a row in your sql query or you can add an additional entity to your datasource or you create your datagrid completely programmatically and not setting the datasource property.

Comment: You can do this with the query modification, but I found this less desirable as sorting placed the *sum row* out of it's proper location at the end of the list. I've created an [extensive answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33399630/3773066) addressing this issue for a `DataTable` sourced `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1):

use a data table as a data source for your DataGridView. Then add a data row to your data table, Data Table has a compute function.

An example of how I would work this around;

```
DataTable dt;
dt = yourDataSource; //add your data source to the Data Table
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr("Price") = dt.Compute("Sum(Price)", "");
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dgvShowAllData.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, create a custom footer row for your dataGridView and populate total value in element within footer row.

Comment: Will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Ngengis' solution worked for my implementation.  My app does not know the name, type, or number of columns in advance, so I needed to tweak it a bit. I made use of an extension method (by Dmytrii Nagirniak) to check that a DataColumn.DataType is numeric:

```
    public static bool IsNumeric(this DataColumn col)
    {
        if (col == null)
            return false;
        var numericTypes = new[] { typeof(Byte), typeof(Decimal), typeof(Double), typeof(Int16), typeof(Int32), typeof(Int64), typeof(SByte), typeof(Single), typeof(UInt16), typeof(UInt32), typeof(UInt64)};
        return numericTypes.Contains(col.DataType);
    }
```

And I used a loop to create the total row. I needed to catch a SyntaxErrorException in case the column name didn't work with the Compute() method (aggregated columns with parenthesis in them fail; using a column alias fixes that problem)

```
        //Total Row
        if (MakeTotalRow == true)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                var colName = dt.Columns[j].ColumnName;
                if (dt.Columns[j].IsNumeric()) //ensure column data can be summed
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dr[j] = dt.Compute("Sum(" + colName + ")", "");
                    }
                    catch (SyntaxErrorException e)
                    {
                        //possible syntax error in the column name 
                    }
                }

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

At the first you must use LINQ entityframework and then:

You should test these code it`s will you handle, for example, your field in database named by 'Price', so try :

step by step ,

1.Make A List<> from your Database :

```
List<Database.tblProduct> Lst=new List<Database.tblProduct>;
```

So you Could Use Query From C#,

```
Textblock.text=lst.Where(w=>w.PriceId==1).sum(w=>w.Price).tostring("#,##");
```

it Could Help you.