# How to sum filtered rows on textbox textchanged?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sum, filtering

I have a textbox that is on a TextChanged event which would allow the user to filter through the datagrid rows. A datatable is bind to the datagrid for datasource. I also have a total row added to the datagrid via the datatable to sum all the rows. I would like to dynamically sum the rows on each filtering. How can I achieve this?

```
  private filterTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     (dgv1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
     string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);
  }

  private string SumColumn(string rowItem)
  {
     return dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x[rowItem].ToString(),
     System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, null)).ToString("c");
  }

  private void dgv1_TotalRow()
  {
     DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
     row["Amount1"] = SumColumn("Amount1");
     row["Amount2"] = SumColumn("Amount2");
     row["Amount3"] = SumColumn("Amount3");
     row["Amount4"] = SumColumn("Amount4");
     dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
  }

  private void Load_DGV()
  {
     dgv1_TotalRow();
     dgv1.DataSource = dataTable;
  }
```

Comment: Don't we need to see the TextChanged event you have?

Comment: added the event

Comment: Playing a devil’s advocate, are you confident “adding” a row to the "grid" is the right approach for this? One issue is if the user is allowed to add rows, then the code is going to have to move the “sum” row to the last row. In addition, after the row is added and then another filter is applied, I am guessing the sum row may not be the last row anymore.

Comment: IMHO, this “sum” value for the columns should be “external” to the grid. I am guessing some well-placed text boxes directly below the grid, would not only be much easier to implement, but would also be user friendly in a sense that the user would not be forced to scroll to the bottom row to get the total if the number of rows extended beyond the grids size. Just a thought.

Comment: The datagrid is readonly

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399630/3773066) where I've extended the `DataGridView` for just this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
private double Sum(DataGridView dgv, string ColumnName)
{
    double sum = 0;

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        sum += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[ColumnName].Value);

    return sum;
}
```

Add this code to that form and at the end of `filterTextBox_TextChanged` event call it like this `TextBoxWhereYouShowSum.Text = Sum(yourDataGridView, ColumnNameToSum).ToString();`