# DataGridView column sort direction is always asc

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I am trying to sort a datagridview with a total row that is data source from a datatable. What I am trying to achieve is to exclude the total row from being sort each time the user click on a datagrid column. I am using the DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs to capture this event. Here is my code:

```
    private void dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {  
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        var columnSortDirection = string.Empty;
        var columnName = dgv.SortedColumn.DataPropertyName;

        if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            columnSortDirection = "DESC";
        }
        else
        {
            columnSortDirection = "ASC";
        }

        //remove total row before sort
        var lastRow = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1];
        dt.Rows.Remove(lastRow);

        //sort datatable
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", columnName, columnSortDirection);
        DataTable sortedDt = dv.ToTable();

        //reinserting total row after dt is sorted
        InsertTotalRow(sortedDt); 
        dgv.DataSource = sortedDt;
    }
```

The code only work for ascending but not the other. For whatever reason it would never change the direction to descending when the user click on the column again. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the `SortGlyphDirection` changes to `SortOrder.Descending` at all? Based on the code the column would display a Glyph, so check the correct Glyph gets assigned upon click.

Comment: Another route:  I've created an inheriting  [`DataTableSumSortableDGV`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399630/3773066) class for this same purpose.